# Firebird 2.5 Ambiguous field name between an alias and a field in the select list with name

Tags: sql, firebird

есть sql запрос на связь многих таблиц используя using и одна из таблиц встречается в каждом элементе, ошибка:

Ambiguous field name between an alias and a field in the select list with name.
ID_DEPARTMENT

как правильно изменить запрос?
Ссылка на запрос https://pastebin.com/t2rqMAut

Comment: А в чем собственно смысл 4 раза делать inner join к одной таблице по одному и тому же ID?

Answer (score 1):

Точно работающий вариант - заменить using на обычное соединение по равенству.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/289768)

Comment: Почему же? Вопрос "как правильно изменить запрос?" - на него дан ответ

Answer (score 1):

Похоже поле ID_DEPARTMENT встречается в четырех разных таблицах. Нужно везде заменить using на явное равенство, поставить у всех таблиц уникальные алиасы и писать имена полей обязательно с ними.